# Replace column value in existing csv and save with same name

Tags: powershell

I am having the below csv file with me

**Ports_data.csv**

```
Server;Port;Open
A1AP;1688;
A1AP;13724;
```

I the script, I have check for the open ports, so the server name is coming from another file

```
$checkList=Import-Csv -Path "E:\Ports_data.csv" -Delimiter ";" -ErrorAction Stop


$TOD_Data= @(Import-Csv -Path "C:\vmdata.csv") #it's a csv file with multiple value present in a single row out of which need to pick only the server name
$Server = $TOD_Data.name #ATU1AP
```

So every time it executes, I have to replace the old server name with the new one which I will be reading.

Need to keep the filename same as this file will be used by other scripts also
expected:

```
Server;Port;Open
ATU1AP;1688;
ATU1AP;13724;
```

Please let me know how can I do that

Comment: You may elaborate a little more detailed what exactly you want to replace with what. What's the content of `E:\Ports_data.csv` and what's the content of `C:\vmdata.csv`?

Comment: @Olaf: Please check the update and let me know if you need any other information

Comment: I still don't see what you want to replace with what. Could you please share some sample data from your `C:\vmdata.csv`?

Comment: @Olaf: If you check in my question. I am fetching servername from `vmdata.csv` file which is `ATU1AP`, but in my `Ports_data.csv`, the servername is `A1AP`. So I want to replace  `A1AP` with `ATU1AP`. hope it is clear now. I have mentioned my expected output also

Comment: Hmmm ... it is just this one name you want to change or are there more?

Comment: @Olaf: Only the servername in `Ports_data.csv`. because every time that will change. rest port numbers will remain same

Answer (score 0):

You are really NOT sharing enough information. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` As I understood your task so far this should be enough:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'E:\Ports_data.csv' -Delimiter ';' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Server = $_.Server -replace 'A1AP','ATU1AP'
        $_
    }
```